# Laravel Error : Undefined variable : $ from views index.blade.php

Tags: laravel

i got this error when trying to fetch from database it says

> Undefined variable: contacts (View: C:\Users\My-Asus\contact_manager\resources\views\contacts\index.blade.php)

the error refer to variable $contacts used at for each looping in the index.blade.php below

```
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('content')

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <table class="table">

    @foreach ($contacts as $contact)
      <tr>
        <td class="middle">
          <div class="media">
            <div class="media-left">
              <a href="#">
                <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="...">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">{{ $contact->name }}</h4>
              <address>
                <strong>{{ $contact->company }}</strong><br>
                {{ $contact->email }}
              </address>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td width="100" class="middle">
          <div>
          {!! Form::open(['route' => ['contacts.destroy', $contact->id], 'method' => 'DELETE']) !!}
            <a href="{{ route('contacts.edit', ['id' => $contact->id]) }}" class="btn btn-circle btn-default btn-xs" title="Edit">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
            </a>
            <button class="btn btn-circle btn-danger btn-xs" title="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Are You sure ?')">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
            </button>

            {!! Form::close() !!}
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>

    @endforeach

    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="text-center">
    <nav>
      {!! $contacts->appends( Request::query() )->render() !!}
    </nav>
  </div>

@endsection
```

i have create the controller like this, is there anything wrong with it?

```
class ContactsController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $contacts = Contact::all();
        return view('contacts.index', compact('contacts'));
    }
}
```

and this is the route (routes/web.php)

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('contacts.index');
});


Route::resource('contacts', 'ContactsController');
```

any help will be apreciated thanks!

Comment: can you show u more code from `C:\Users\My-Asus\contact_manager\resources\views\contacts\index.blade.php)`

Answer (score 2):

**You are returning '/' directly into view page. So that's why it is not getting the contacts variable from controller .**

*In your web.php file,*

```
Route::get('/', 'ContactController@index')->name('/');
```

**Now try clearing cache and routes using**

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:clear
```

*Let me know if you are still facing the issue*

**OR**

*directy call this in route*

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    $contacts = \App\Contact::all();
    return view('contacts.index',compact('contacts'));
});
```

Comment: it doesnt work, it still say undefined index : contacts

Comment: `compact('contacts ')` ... that typo is how i can tell this was copy and pasted

Comment: please mark as verified this answer if its help for you THANK YOU...

Answer (score 2):

In `route.php` file, you're calling `view('contacts.index')` but no `contacts` with `compact` data.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('contacts.index');
});
```

but when you call the `/contacts` the resource will call index method.

```
Route::resource('contacts', 'ContactsController');
```

So your code will work with `/contacts` and if you want to use with same `'/'` url you have to `compact('contacts')` in route file as below.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    $contacts = \App\Contact::all();
    return view('contacts.index',compact('contacts'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

*I think you have call `"index.blade.php"` directly through routes.You have to call the method index of `"ContactsController"`.*

Remove the route code of yours and use below code in route file :

```
Route::get('/', 'ContactsController@index');
```